# API list Is only returning the last item, not all of the list

Tags: python, string, list, api

```
endpoint = 'http://api.yelp.com/v3/categories' #url categories 
headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer %s'% api_key} #making it bearer, not changing it throughout 

response3 = requests.get(url = endpoint, headers = headers)
business_data2 = response3.json()

for item in business_data2['categories']:
     itemname = item['title']
```

If I say

```
itemname = item['title']
```

and I get only the last thing in my API

But if I say

```
print(item['title'])
```

I get all my list but only in my for loop.
I tried to do that in terminal
and I got only the last string

I don't know how to fix it
I tried to index it by saying `[0:-1]` but I only get the last element as well.

Answer (score 1):

By doing the following, you keep overwriting `itemname` value, so you see only the last one

```
for item in business_data2['categories']:
    itemname = item['title']
```

To collect them all use a `list`

```py
itemnames = [] 
for item in business_data2['categories']:
    itemnames.append(item['title'])


# or directly a list comprehension
itemnames = [item['title'] for item in business_data2['categories']]

# pythonic equivalent
from operator import itemgetter
itemnames = list(map(itemgetter('title'), business_data2['categories']))
```